# Flutter GridView can be trigger with tap?

Tags: flutter, gridview, touch

I have created a flutter app, i would like to the Item can be tap, Is it possible to trigger the grid view when it is tapped? Please help me, How to do it?. below is the code from the dashboard.dart

```
class DashBoard extends StatelessWidget {
  Item item1 = new Item(
      img: "assets/home/calendar.png");
  Item item2 = new Item(
      img: "assets/home/clock.png");
  Item item3 = new Item(
      img: "assets/home/todo.png");
  Item item4 = new Item(
      img: "assets/home/teacher.png");
  Item item5 = new Item(
      img: "assets/home/settings.png");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Item> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5];
    var color = 0xff453658;

    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 25,
        mainAxisSpacing: 25,
        children: myList.map((data) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(color),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(data.img, width: 45),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),   
                ]),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can wrap `Container` with `GestureDetector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `Container` with `GestureDetector` as the following

```dart
return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 25,
        mainAxisSpacing: 25,
        children: myList.map((data) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              performAction(data); // create action handling method
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(color),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(data.img, width: 45),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I would use an InkWell rather than a gesture detector, as it is more focused towards the desired result. It also already has builtin functionality for splash and hover if that is desired in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the container in an InkWell widget, and set the onTap method for that.

```
return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 25,
        mainAxisSpacing: 25,
        children: myList.map((data) {
          return InkWell(
            focusColor: Colors.transparent,
            hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
            highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            onTap: (){
              print("pressed");
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(color),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(data.img, width: 45),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),   
                  ]),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
```